# get json No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' error - phone gap

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, cordova

I keep getting this error when trying to retrieve and display information in my phonegap application.

This is the error I get:

GET http://192.168.0.4:3000/Application/www/retrieveSymbol.php send @ jquery-2.2.0.js:9172jQuery.extend.ajax @ jquery-2.2.0.js:8653jQuery.(anonymous function) @ jquery-2.2.0.js:8804jQuery.extend.getJSON @ jquery-2.2.0.js:8785(anonymous function) @ bookmarks.html:44
bookmarks.html:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://192.168.0.4:3000/Application/www/retrieveSymbol.php. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.

This is the code:

```
<script>
//populates product container
$(" #productContainer").html('');
$.getJSON("http://192.168.0.4:3000/Application/www/retrieveSymbol.php", function(data){  //retrieves json array
  $.each(data, function(i, field){          //loops through array
    $("#productContainer").append(          //creates product box filling it with data
      "<div id='productBox'>" + "<div id='name'>" + field[1] + " </div>" + "<br>" +
      "<div id='image'>" + "<img id='image' src='Images/" + field[5] + "'/>" + "</div>" +
      "<div id='description'>" + "<b>Description:</b> "  + "<br>" + field[2]  + " </div>" + "" +
      "<div id='price'>" + "£" + field[3] + " </div>" + "<br><br>" +  "<br>" +

      //gets name and price and sends data to basket when button is clicked
      "<form action='Basket.php' method='post' id='add'>" +
      "<input type='hidden' name='itemName' value=" + field[1] + "/>" +
      "<input type='hidden' name='itemPrice' value=" + field[3] + ">" +
      "<input id='addButton'type='submit' value='Add to Cart'>" +
      "</form>" + "</div>"

    );
  });
});
</script>
```

recieveSymbol.php

```
<?php

//connect to the database
$mysqli = NEW MySQLi ('localhost','root','','contentdatabase');
//query database
$resultSet = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM items");
//count the rows
if($resultSet->num_rows != 0) {
  //turn the results into an array
  $rows = $resultSet->fetch_all();
  echo json_encode($rows);

}else{
  echo "{no connection}";
}
?>
```

Can anyone point out why this is happening?

Comment: to `receiveSymbol.php` add the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header - that seems to be what it is complaining about

Comment: enable CORS in your server script. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/9866124/1175966

Comment: Do you test in device or emulator?

Answer (score 0):

This is typical cross-origin error that can be seen in most PhoneGap projects. Please review this answer for further details and solutions.

[No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' in PhoneGap/Cordova, as well as the latest versions of Google Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27971189/xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-no-access-control-allow-origin-sencha-touch/27979776#27979776)

Comment: Also, try this for chrome windows - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24290149/creating-google-chrome-shortcut-with-disable-web-security

Answer (score 0):

use this chrome extension [Allow-Control-Allow-Origin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi), it allows you to request any site with ajax from any source